# Jest testing stuck at setDoc forever (Firestore)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I am using `jest` to test my Firestore implementation on my expo app with Firebase Emulator. For some reason, the execution always stuck at the `setDoc` and never return which causing a timeout.

I have tried the firebase SDK and `firebase-admin`. For the `firebase-admin` I am able to see the new information are added into firestore but the `setDoc` never return.With firebase SDK, no information are written.

I am using `jsdom` for my jest test environemnt. And I have tired to use `jest-environment-jsdom` but no luck.

I have ensure that the firebase emulator are running and it is at port `8080`.

Here are the snipper of the code I used.

```js
// App.test.tx
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {collection, connectFirestoreEmulator, doc, getFirestore, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {API_KEY, APP_ID, AUTH_DOMAIN, MEASUREMENT_ID, MESSAGING_SENDER_ID, PROJECT_ID, STORAGE_BUCKET} from '@env';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: APP_ID,
  measurementId: MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

describe('Firebase', () => {
  jest.setTimeout(30000)
  it('should initialize Firebase', async () => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080)
    await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
      name: "Los Angeles",
      state: "CA",
      country: "USA"
    });
  });
});
```

```js
// jest.config.ts
const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  setupFiles: ['./jest_setup/asyncStorage.ts'],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
        babelConfig: 'babel.config.js'
      },
    ],
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)',
  ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    '!**/coverage/**',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/babel.config.js',
    '!**/jest.setup.js',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'ts',
    'tsx',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|@react-navigation/native-stack|@firebase|firebase/.*|@react-native|react-native)',
  ],
  coverageReporters: [
    'json-summary',
    'text',
    'lcov',
  ],
};
```

```json
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
        "@jest/globals": "^29.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
        "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
        "@types/react-dom": "~18.0.10",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
        "@types/validator": "^13.7.17",
        "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
        "jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4"
    },
```

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and let me know if that helps. This may be an ipv6 vs ipv4 issue

Comment: I tried 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' and '10.0.2.2'. I got the same behaviour. Always timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running emulators and tests as different scripts? if so they don't automatically see each other unless you use `firebase emulators:exec`.

You can try either of the following options.

```bash
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 npm run test
```

Or set `process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080` before you call `initalizeApp`/`getFirestore`.

I had a similar problem (with `firebase-admin`) and as far as I remember the two above functions check and internalise `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` the first time they are called.

---

Here is a script I use to access a development database and then seed a local emulator database.

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app')
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

(async () => {
  const app = initializeApp({
    credential: cert(require('./service-account.json')),
    databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
  }, '<APP_NAME>')
  const appFirestore = getFirestore(app)

  const foos = await Promise.all(['THIS_FOO', 'THAT_FOO', 'THE_OTHER_FOO'].map(fooId => {
    return appFirestore
      .collection('foo')
      .doc(fooId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          throw new Error(`foo {${fooId}} does not exist.`)
        } else {
          return doc.data()
        }
      })
  }))

  // Access Prod and local firestore in the same script
  // REF: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/776#issuecomment-1322803407
  process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:9099'
  process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8080'

  const emulatorApp = initializeApp({
    projectId: 'demo-test'
  }, 'default')

  const emulatorAppFirestore = getFirestore(emulatorApp)

  await Promise.all(foos.map(foo => {
    return emulatorAppFirestore.collection('foo').doc(foo.id).set(foo)
  }))

  process.exit()
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer could be valid for `firebase-admin`, but the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` env variable is not used for the web SDK.

I was having the same issue and I'm not sure yet why it happens exactly, only that it's related to using the *jsdom testing environment*, but I did manage to work around the problem.

When initializing the `firestore` instance, use `initializeFirestore()` instead of `getFirestore()` and make sure to pass the `useFetchStreams: false` option:

```
const testFirestore = initializeFirestore(testApp, {
  useFetchStreams: false,
})
```

> Note: you may get a type error, as the property is not exposed publicly anymore.

The default for `useFetchStreams` is `true` since `firebase@v9` and it seems that the `jsdom` environment is not properly supporting `fetch readable streams`. By setting it to `false`, firestore fallbacks to using `XHR` for streaming data.

Here's the open issue on the Firebase JS SDK repository: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7808

It's more of a workaround than a solution though.